# PHP Header redirect issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code that works well and can actually insert data. My problem is in the redirecting back to the page I was from. I have an index.html and add_cars.php

The index.html is like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#search').keyup(function(){
                var search = $('#search').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'search.php',
                    data:{search:search},
                    type:'POST',
                    success:function(data){
                        if(!data.error){
                            $('#result').html(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }); // Search function end

            $("#add-car-form").submit(function(evt){
                evt.preventDefault();

                var postData = $(this).serialize();

                var url = $(this).attr('action');

                $.post(url, postData, function(php_table_data){
                     $("#car-result").html(php_table_data);
                });
            }); // add car function end

        }); // Document ready function end
    </script>

    <div id="container" class='col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3'>
        <div class="row">
            <h2 >Search the Database</h2>

            <input type="text" name="" class='form-control' name='search' id='search' placeholder='Search our inventory'>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h2 class="bg-success" id="result"> 
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <form id="add-car-form" class="col-xs-6" action="add_cars.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="car_name" placeholder="Car name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"> 
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Car" name="">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div  id="car-result">Sometkasdf</div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my add_cars.php is like so:

```
<?php  
    include("db.php");

     if(isset($_POST['car_name'])){
        $car_name = $_POST['car_name'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO cars(car) VALUES ('$car_name')";
        $query_car_name = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(!$query_car_name){
            die("QUERY FAILED");
        }
        header("Location: index.html");
        exit;
     }
?>
```

When I redirect back to my index.html, I am getting two forms. It's like the first form is copied at the end of it. To be exact, the first form is copied to the #car-result div. What should happen is; it should go back to my index.html and the input box should only have the placeholder value. What am I doing wrong here or what should I do? All help is appreciated.

Comment: when you are using ajax then redirection is not a good choice to have.

Comment: You are using an ajax call to call `add_cars.php`. Since you redirect in `add_cars.php` to `index.html` the ajax call will get `index.html` as a response. `index.html` contains the form. You put that form into `$("#car-result")` which is located below the form that was already there. So you get two forms.

Comment: Remove the header part from .php

Comment: Just use your `data.error` for client-side redirect.

Comment: @vp_arth: Where should I put the data.error? How do I implement it that it goes back to my index.html with only one form and no value in the input text?

Comment: I don't know where. Why you wrote `if(!data.error){`? May be it should be json response with correct header sometimes?

Comment: I'm sure it's not json because I do not know that yet :). I just placed the !data.error just in case there is an error in the response. What I'm actually asking is how can I return to my index.html as soon as the data is added and with the input blank.